# WHERE statement on a relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have two tables : `Place` and `Description`

A place can contains 0, 1 or more descriptions.

So in **Place** entity, I have a descriptions field:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Description", mappedBy="place")
 */
private $descriptions;
```

And in **Description** entity I have a place field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="descriptions")
 */
private $place;
```

I would like to use the QueryBuilder to get descriptions based on a Place's field. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM Description WHERE Place.id = 439483
```

I guess I should use join, but it also returns Places column. How could I just get descriptions based on a Place condition?

Thanks

**EDIT: Here is what I tried:**

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $placeRepository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Place");
        $q = $placeRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select("d")
            ->innerJoin("p.descriptions", "d")
            ->where("p.id = 439483");

        $q = $q->getQuery();
        $res = $q->getResult();

        return $res;
```

But it returns a place and descriptions, I just want descriptions.

Comment: Show us your QueryBuilder construction, please.

Comment: [Doctrine createQueryBuilder and createQuery examples](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/znlh/doctrine-createquerybuilder-and-createuery-examples)

Answer (score 0):

next time do post what you actually tried. But as this is a simple query, here:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $placeRepository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Place");
            $q = $placeRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select("d")
                ->innerJoin("p.descriptions", "d")
                ->where("p.id = 439483");

            $q = $q->getQuery();
            $res = $q->getResult();

            return $res;
```

Comment: I guess he wants only return Descriptions. It will return a Place with all descriptions inside.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried. And indeed the problem is that I don't want place but only descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the description(s) associated with a place, you can do this:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$descriptionRepository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Description");
$q = $descriptionRepository->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->select("d")
    ->innerJoin("d.place", "p")
    ->where("p.id = 439483");

$q = $q->getQuery();
$res = $q->getResult();

return $res;
```

Comment: @damien did you see this answer? Did it helped you?